# How can I run Qemu with the “-nographic” option in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, virtualization, console, qemu, tty

Does anyone know how to run [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) with the `-nographic` option in Mac OS X? The idea is to use the native Terminal for a text based operation instead of running inside Qemu’s own window.

The `-nographic` option starts Qemu with no output at all, there's also a `-chardev` option that can be used with “serial” and `path=/dev/tty*`. However I haven’t been able to pull any of these options off to get it to work. The serial option specifically want’s a unique id, but I have no idea what the id is supposed to be. The syntax is also a bit peculiar with a mix of commas and equal signs behind a group of options. From the man page of `-chardev` for example: `-chardev serial ,id=id ,path=path`.

Google has given some hints how it can be done, but those examples have all been Linux specific.